# Displaying vertex-labels and weights at vertex. Unexpected error (UPDATE AS BELOW)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The problem I flagged still occurs after replacing Vertexweights by VertexWeight.

The weights are displayed on the graph by $Failed for the following code, but work fine for the code produced after (the only difference is that I used

```
temp = SetProperty
```

rather than

```
SetProperty
```

I don't see why this should be the case (I flagged a part of the code that showed up highlighted in blue at the end of this post).

Code which fails

```
temp = Graph[{x2 \[DirectedEdge] x1, x2 \[DirectedEdge] x4, 
   x5 \[DirectedEdge] x1, x5 \[DirectedEdge] x4, 
   x3 \[DirectedEdge] x2}]
SetProperty[temp, 
 VertexCoordinates -> 
  ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]@GraphEmbedding[temp]]
SetProperty[temp, VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
SetProperty[temp, {VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
     Placed[{"Name", 
       AnnotationValue[{temp, v}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}]}, 
  ImagePadding -> 20}]
```

Code which works

```
temp = Graph[{x2 \[DirectedEdge] x1, x2 \[DirectedEdge] x4, 
   x5 \[DirectedEdge] x1, x5 \[DirectedEdge] x4, 
   x3 \[DirectedEdge] x2}]
temp = SetProperty[temp, 
  VertexCoordinates -> 
   ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]@GraphEmbedding[temp]]
temp = SetProperty[temp, VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
temp = SetProperty[
  temp, {VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
      Placed[{"Name", 
        AnnotationValue[{temp, v}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 20}]
```

The only part that is highlighted in blue when I write the code is the use of x1 (and the others: x2 x3 x4 x5) in the first line of the code

```
Graph[{x2 \[DirectedEdge] x1, x2 \[DirectedEdge] x4, 
   x5 \[DirectedEdge] x1, x5 \[DirectedEdge] x4, 
   x3 \[DirectedEdge] x2}]
```

Comment: replace `VertexWeights` with `VertexWeight`?

Comment: That worked. Oddly, VertexWeights did not produce an error.

Comment: `SetProperty`  (and `Annotate`) does not produce errors because it is supposed to work to add custom properties (which may have arbitrary names). So the only clue that `VertexWeights` may be problematic is the blue syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I'll keep an eye out for blue syntax.

Comment: I get the same error for this code (using VertexWeight).

Comment: @kglr the error still occurs for the updated edit of the code after replacing VertexWeights by VertexWeight. I indicated at the end what part highlights in blue when I run the code. For one version it works perfectly, for the other it fails. The only difference seems that I use temp = SetProperty in the one that works and SetProperty on its own in the other.

Comment: I only have VertexWeights in the part I originally posted (below the ***** line). The two code blocks I posted above it don't have it (?). I did a search to make sure (?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120189/discussion-between-mike-and-kglr).

Comment: `SetProperty` _"produce(s) an object with a modified property value."_ It does not do modification _in place_.  So you need to use  `temp  = SetProperty[temp,...]` (as you in the last code block) to make the properties stick to `temp`.

Comment: thanks that is clear.

Comment: Mike, posted the comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`SetProperty >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetProperty.html)

[image]

That is, `SetProperty[obj,...]` does not modify properties *in place*. We need to do `obj = SetProperty[obj, ...]` to modify the properties of `obj`.

Illustration using a simple example:

```
g0 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}];
PropertyValue[g0, EdgeStyle]
```

> ```
> Automatic
> ```

```
SetProperty[g0, EdgeStyle -> {(1 -> 2) -> Red, (2 -> 3) -> Green}]
```

[image]

```
PropertyValue[g0, EdgeStyle]
```

> ```
> Automatic
> ```

```
g0 = SetProperty[g0, EdgeStyle -> {(1 -> 2) -> Red, (2 -> 3) -> Green}];

PropertyValue[g0, EdgeStyle]
```

[image]